# Aggregating daily data to weekly, ending today

Tags: r, time-series

I'm currently building some charts of covid-related data....my script goes out and downloads most recent data and goes from there.  I wind up with dataframes that look like

```
head(NMdata)

    Date state positiveIncrease totalTestResultsIncrease
1 2020-05-19    NM              158                     4367
2 2020-05-18    NM               81                     4669
3 2020-05-17    NM              195                     4126
4 2020-05-16    NM              159                     4857
5 2020-05-15    NM              139                     4590
6 2020-05-14    NM              152                     4722
```

I've been aggregating to weekly data using the `tq_transmute` function from `tidyquant`.

```
NMweeklyPos <- NMdata %>% tq_transmute(select = positiveIncrease, mutate_fun = apply.weekly, FUN=sum)
```

This works, but it aggregates on week of the year, with weeks starting on Sunday.

```
head(NMweeklyPos)

Date                positiveIncrease
  <dttm>                         <int>
1 2020-03-08 00:00:00                0
2 2020-03-15 00:00:00               13
3 2020-03-22 00:00:00               44
4 2020-03-29 00:00:00              180
5 2020-04-05 00:00:00              306
6 2020-04-12 00:00:00              631
```

So for instance if I ran it today (which happens to be a Wednesday) my last entry is a partial week with Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.

```
tail(NMweeklyPos)

 Date                positiveIncrease
  <dttm>                         <int>
1 2020-04-19 00:00:00              624
2 2020-04-26 00:00:00              862
3 2020-05-03 00:00:00             1072
4 2020-05-10 00:00:00             1046
5 2020-05-17 00:00:00             1079
6 2020-05-19 00:00:00              239
```

For purposes of my chart this winds up being a small value, and so I have been discarding the partial weeks at the end, but that means I'm throwing out the most recent data.

I would prefer the throw out a partial week from the start of the dataset and have the aggregation automatically use weeks that end on whatever day the script is being run. So if I ran it today (Wednesday) it would aggregate on weeks ending Wednesday so that I had the most current data included...I could drop the partial week from the beginning of the data.  But tomorrow it would choose weeks ending Thursday, etc.  And I don't want to have to hardcode the week end day and change it each time.

How can I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using lubridate, the below code will find what day of the week it is and define that day as the floor for each week.

Hope this helps!

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

end = as.Date("2020-04-14")
data = data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), end, by = "day"),
  val = 1
)

# get the day of the week
weekday = wday(end)

# using the floor_date function we can use todays date to determine what day of the week will be our floor
data%>%
  mutate(week = floor_date(date, "week", week_start = weekday))%>%
  group_by(week)%>%
  summarise(total = sum(val))
```

Comment: that did!  thanks...you wouldn't know how to tell ggplot to shift x-axis labels though would you?  I'll probably post a new question.  It wants to make the x-axis ticks start on Mondays (I guess because it recognizes they're dates) but that doesn't line up with my columns now, which are based on weeks ending on Wednesdays....